# MS SQL correlated sub queries, Unable to write outer query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a sub query and it doesn’t allow me to continue. What is the wrong and how to achieve this?

Error: Incorrect syntax near 'A'.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT ID, 
        CAST([dbo].[SC_GetVersionedFieldValue](ID, '{25BED78C-4957-4165-998A-CA1B52F67497}') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS '__Created',
        CAST([dbo].[SC_GetVersionedFieldValue](ID, '{D9CF14B1-FA16-4BA6-9288-E8A174D4D522}') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS '__Updated'
    FROM [dbo].[Items] WHERE [TemplateID] = '{8CB33CED-3E7E-4263-AF97-71B22338D9C7}'        
) mytable A WHERE exists (SELECT ID FROM mytable B WHERE A.ID = B.ID) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove comma before `FROM`, most likely this is causing the error

Comment: your query is having `'AS '__Updated', FROM`

Comment: SELECT * FROM 
(
 SELECT ID, 
  CAST([dbo].[SC_GetVersionedFieldValue](ID, '{25BED78C-4957-4165-998A-CA1B52F67497}') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS '__Created',
  CAST([dbo].[SC_GetVersionedFieldValue](ID, '{D9CF14B1-FA16-4BA6-9288-E8A174D4D522}') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS '__Updated'
 FROM [dbo].[Items] WHERE [TemplateID] = '{8CB33CED-3E7E-4263-AF97-71B22338D9C7}'  
) mytable A; This part of query working fine but it doesnt allow me to created alias of the table and write subquery.

Comment: Ok so your earlier syntax error is solved and you got a new one. Have you tried @Parado solutions?

Comment: Parado solution doesn’t make any sense.  “Mytable” is an alias it’s not a physical table.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove `mytable` and as @harsh [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21626120/1579182) remove comma. Try below code.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT ID, 
        CAST([dbo].[SC_GetVersionedFieldValue](ID, '{25BED78C-4957-4165-998A-CA1B52F67497}') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS '__Created',
        CAST([dbo].[SC_GetVersionedFieldValue](ID, '{D9CF14B1-FA16-4BA6-9288-E8A174D4D522}') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS '__Updated'
    FROM [dbo].[Items] WHERE [TemplateID] = '{8CB33CED-3E7E-4263-AF97-71B22338D9C7}'        
) A 
    WHERE exists (SELECT ID FROM mytable B WHER A.ID = B.ID) ;
```